# React Native Drawer Navigation show headerLeft

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-drawer

I have a Drawer navigator which is inside a Stack navigator and I'd like to display a header. Currently I can display everything I want however because the header is defined at the Stack level the navigation inside the header is stack level not drawer level which is preventing me from opening the drawer.

Root stack

```
<Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={"Splash"}
      screenOptions={{}}
      component={SplashScreen}
    >
      { auth ? 
        <Stack.Screen name="Drawer" component={DrawerStack}  options={({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'My App', 
          headerLeft: () => (
            <HeaderLeft navigation={ navigation } />
          ),
          headerRight: () => (
            <HeaderRight navigation={ navigation } />
          ),
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTintColor: 'white',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#5742f5'
          },
        })} />
      : 
        <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStack} options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}/>
      }
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Drawer stack

```
<Drawer.Navigator options={{
            headerShown: true,
            headerLeft: () => (
                <HeaderLeft navigation={ navigation } />
            ),
        }}>
            <Drawer.Screen 
                name="Conversations" 
                options={{
                    title: props.title,
                }} 
                component={ChatListScreen}
            />
            <Drawer.Screen 
                name="ChatRoom" 
                options={{
                    drawerLabel: () => null,
                    title: null,
                    drawerIcon: () => null
                }} 
                component={ChatRoomScreen}
            />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Note in the drawer navigator the line with `headerLeft` does nothing and is there to show where I attempted to put it thinking it would work. I did think it might be overlaying the stack one so I commented out the stack one and it didn't work.

HeaderLeft

```
export default function HeaderLeft ({ navigation }) {

    const openMenu = () => {
        navigation.toggleDrawer();
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Icon name='menu' onPress={openMenu} size={28} style={styles.icon} color="white"/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

My question is how can I refactor this to enable me to have the HeaderLeft component work to open the drawer. I will be adding more screens so ideally something I don't have to pass to each screen but if that is what works I am good with it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Options` in `DrawerStack` not work. I modified it:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerLeft: () => <HeaderLeft />,
  }}>
  // ...
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

And a little change in `HeaderLeft`:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HeaderLeft() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const openMenu = () => {
    navigation.toggleDrawer();
  };

  // render your Button
}
```

Demo: https://snack.expo.dev/@pqv2210/0d613b

Comment: Thank you! The screen options solved the issue with the header and the change to import navigation makes things a lot cleaner too. I had tried that before but found 2 stack overflow posts where people said it didn't work anymore they were both from 2021. Used that change in the right header too to make it cleaner